# I am a celery beginner, stuck in the very elementary usages... Cannot even get into the task.delay()

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, celery-task

I was trying to add Celery asychronized feature to my simple flask web project as a flask beginner. After managing to install and launching celery, redis and related python pip thing, I got struggling with the delay() in the very beginning. It seemed I could not even get into the delay(). I am so frustrated, could you help me please?

I have app.py and tasks.py under my flask project. (At first I wrote everything in app.py, then I split the celery object out, which didn't help)

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('app', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/1')


@celery.task
def modeling_task():
    print('yes')
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('/train', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def train():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('train.html')
    else:  # when request POST
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return jsonify({"code": 500, "status": 'No file is uploaded!'})

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print(request.files['file'].filename)
            print('before task')
            task = modeling_task.delay()
            print('after task')

            return jsonify({"code": 200, "status": 'model training', "task_id": task.id})

        return 'Uploading file is wrong'
```

If things work well, after the server receives a uploading file, the print results on console should be

```
Car_TEST.csv
before task
yes
after task
```

However, the console result is simply this

```
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\headmaster\\Desktop\\WEB\\tasks.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 308-608-393
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2020 11:39:22] "GET /train HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Car_TEST.csv
before task
```

and the server got stuck in here, keeping enlessly running.

So it seems the server don't even run the "task = modeling_task.delay()", otherwise it should've print "yes" on the console, right?

Would it print "yes" in another place? Why did it get stuck?

**`celery report` Output:**

```
(base) C:\Users\headmaster\Desktop\WEB>celery -A tasks report

software -> celery:4.4.2 (cliffs) kombu:4.6.8 py:3.7.4
            billiard:3.6.3.0 redis:3.4.1
platform -> system:Windows arch:64bit, WindowsPE
            kernel version:10 imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:redis results:redis://localhost:6379/1

broker_url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
result_backend: 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
```

Down below is the celery info:

```
(base) C:\Users\headmaster\Desktop\WEB>celery worker -A tasks.celery --loglevel=info

 -------------- celery@LAPTOP-KLKJCK2F v4.4.2 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2020-04-22 10:55:13
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app:0x2526977ac08
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/1
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.modeling_task

[2020-04-22 10:55:15,501: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 6692 calling self.run()
[2020-04-22 10:55:15,511: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 17736 calling self.run()
[2020-04-22 10:55:15,518: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 16320 calling self.run()
[2020-04-22 10:55:15,571: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 5608 calling self.run()
[2020-04-22 10:55:15,972: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2020-04-22 10:55:20,332: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-04-22 10:55:27,369: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-04-22 10:55:35,402: INFO/MainProcess] celery@LAPTOP-KLKJCK2F ready.
```

redis info:

````
PS D:\Applications\Redis> redis-server redis.conf
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.2.100 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 21420
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

[21420] 22 Apr 10:38:22.506 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.100
[21420] 22 Apr 10:38:22.508 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
[21420] 22 Apr 10:38:22.508 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
[21420] 22 Apr 10:43:23.025 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
[21420] 22 Apr 10:43:23.030 * Background saving started by pid 6204
[21420] 22 Apr 10:43:23.231 # fork operation complete
[21420] 22 Apr 10:43:23.232 * Background saving terminated with success
[21420] 22 Apr 10:51:18.099 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
[21420] 22 Apr 10:51:18.103 * Background saving started by pid 10116
[21420] 22 Apr 10:51:18.305 # fork operation complete
[21420] 22 Apr 10:51:18.306 * Background saving terminated with success
[21420] 22 Apr 10:56:19.022 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
[21420] 22 Apr 10:56:19.026 * Background saving started by pid 11748
[21420] 22 Apr 10:56:19.227 # fork operation complete
[21420] 22 Apr 10:56:19.227 * Background saving terminated with success
````

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit stale, but hopefully this helps you.

Basically flask could block the process, and not allow the celery function call/task generation on windows in a dev env (even with the fork processes set), and even when leveraging info from here https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/21/celery-4-windows/

If you had a production setup you were porting to windows, you might not see the issue. I would suggest installing a wsgi wrapper for the flask app in a dev env on windows.

create a file named `wsgi.py`

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer # <--- install gevent if you dont have it
from app import app # <--- flask app

http_server = WSGIServer(('', <port>), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Tested on windows with `celery 4.4.6`, `redis` port for windows